# Angular 4: Disabling nested form validators

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to disable the "addressLine1" validator; how can i disable it? seeing at it is nested inside of "address" element

```
 this.form = fb.group({           
            'region': [null, Validators.required],

            'address': fb.group({               
                'addressLine1': ["", Validators.required],
                'addressLine2': [""],
                'city': ["", Validators.required]             
            }),

        })
```

I tried this below but it did not work

```
 this.form.controls["address"]["addressLine1"] .disable();
```

Thank you

Here is the html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

<div ><label><span class="required">*</span>State/Province/Region<br><input class="form-control" pInputText formControlName="addressLine1" [(ngModel)]="selected.address.addressLine1" required></label></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
(this.form.controls["address"] as FormGroup).controls["addressLine1"].disable({});
```

or even better

```
this.form.get('address.addressLine1').disable();
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9w2gu?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)**

**Update**

To disable validator use the following code:

```
const control = this.form.get('address.addressLine1');
control.setValidators(null);
control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19bgqs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: they disabled the whole field instead of just disabling the validator checks

Comment: What do you expect when calling `disable` method?

Comment: i want it to just disable the validator for that field so i can save the form without having input in that field

Answer (score 1):

We need to pass parameters to `disable` method as docs says us:

[image]

So if you don't need to pass any parameters, just pass an empty object, and the code should look like this:

```
this.form.controls["address"]["addressLine1"].disable({});
```

Comment: @BadGuyKUTA, didn't you forget to add `[formGroup]="form"` to your `form` element and `formControlName="addressLine1"` (the example for addressLine1 control) on your `input`s?

Comment: i just edited original post and added the html it has formControlName as that already

Comment: @BadGuyKUTA, and form tag looks like this: `<form [formGroup]="form">`?

Comment: Correct <form [formGroup]="form">; i think my error is how i am referencing it somewhere here this.form.controls["address"]["addressLine1"] .disable();

Comment: @BadGuyKUTA, I just tried in my project, it should be `this.form.controls["address"]["addressLine1"].disable({});`, we should pass a parameter to `disable` method. Try that, it should do the trick

Comment: @BadGuyKUTA, if it will not work, it means that it's something wrong with the path to this method. If so, you can console.log your form and you will find the proper path to this, I did it in my project when searched for the solution

Comment: Worked (kind of) --  
they disabled the whole field instead of just disabling the validator checks

Comment: It should not work. Have you tried it? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jew1n7?file=app/app.component.ts